# Using Left Shift operator with ones at the right of the number

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I'm not very familiar with bit operators and I have this use case : when we use the left shift operator `<<` in `C++` the number will be shifted and 0 will be placed at the right of number, I want to place 1 and not zero at the right.
I mean if I have a number `00000000` and I make << 3 the result need to be `00000111` and not 0 !

Comment: What is you have a number other than `0b00000000`? What is supposed to happen, generally? This question is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that works on any number:

```
int one_shift(int val, int n) {
    return ~(~0 << n) | (val << n);
}
```

Breakdown:

- `~0` evaluates to 0xFFFFFFFF e.g. all 1's
- `~0 << n` shifts 0xFFFFFFFF by N places, resulting in a number with N zeroes on the end
- `~(~0 << n)` flips all these bits, resulting in a number with only the last N bits set
- `| (val << n)` then does a regular left shift on our original number by N places, and sets the last N bits by oring it with our other value

Also, here's a version that works on any integer type:

```
template<typename T>
T one_shift(T val, int n) {
    return ~(~static_cast<T>(0) << n) | (val << n);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple approach is to left shift `1` by the number of bits you want set and then subtract `1`

```
(1 << n) - 1
```

E.g.

```
cout << (1 << 2) - 1 << '\n'; // prints 3
cout << (1 << 3) - 1 << '\n'; // prints 7
cout << (1 << 4) - 1 << '\n'; // prints 15
cout << (1 << 5) - 1 << '\n'; // prints 31
```

But note this only works if `n` is less than the number of bits in an integer. Otherwise it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Amazing that this was getting up votes when it was clearly wrong. Hopefully it's correct now.

Comment: from the beginning you put the correct format : (1 << n) - 1 and this was the answer I'm looking for ! when It was incorrect !

Comment: "it was clearly wrong"... the algorithm was ok and "well known". By reading that one, I thought it is ok. Giving a wrong example... hey what... the algorithm was the solution... So please downvote my upvote :-)

Comment: But this only works on 0, I got the impression @Makkaouu wanted a general solution

Answer (score -3):

Then that's not what a left shift is.

You will have to set those bits to `1` yourself.

Comment: It is not a shift... you must do "something"... helpful?

Comment: YES I'm not asking if the simple shift operator can do this or not, I was asking about a tip to use it with the shift operator to whatever I want, the accepted answer meets my need

Comment: @Klaus Questions asks how to make the shift operator put ones at the end. It can't. Because that's not a shift.

Comment: You are right if you read the question without giving it a sense. It is up to you to downvote, vote for close or give a helpful comment. Simply give a comment as an answer is not what I expect on SO. As we see, others have read the intention of OPs question and are able to help...